# What is Ambipolar Diffusion in semiconductors?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

I am following Neamen's book "*Semiconductor Physics and Devices*". I just could not come to imagine what Ambipolar Diffusion is and feeling very dumb.
This concept of both carriers moving together is unintuitive, more so inconceivable to me.

Quoting the textbook, Pg[201].

> If a pulse of excess electrons and a pulse of excess holes are created at a particular point in semiconductors with applied electric field, the excess holes and electrons will *tend* to drift in opposite directions. However, because the electrons and holes are charged particles, any separation will induce an internal electric field between the two sets of particles. This internal electric field will create a force attracting the electrons and holes backwards toward each other. .... The negatively charged electrons and positively charged holes then will drift or diffuse together with single effective mobility and diffusion coefficient. This phenomenon is called *Ambipolar Diffusion*.

My Ideation.

I assume as he stated earlier that there is low injection. That could mean there is little or no contribution of minorities to begin with. Could it be that these minority carriers are influenced by a few of the majorities and have "clubbed" together with them? I mean, some majority carriers are pulling through these minority carriers. But how could the internal electric field be so much more stronger than the applied electric field such that keeps them together? What happens without low injection?

Rant.

I thought I'll make quick work of this book but having no prior background in Quantum Mechanics or Solid State Physics is causing great impediment. Also as an Engineering student, these equations are boggling.

Answer (score -1):

I received no answers. Here's what I think.

The idea is or could be ported from Plasma Physics. Just as we believed the carriers within semiconductor to possess semi-classical particle properties and thus admissible to diffusion. Ambipolar diffusion is essentially observed in plasma when an electric field is applied.
But, plasma is not equivalent to a semiconductor. Out of the many differences, ions are not free to move within a semiconductor. However, we do have a special quasiparticle within, which could be interpreted as a positively charged particle - "hole".

The key concept in Ambipolar Diffusion is the difference in mobility of the two charged particle groups involved. Upon external influence, the one of them may (does) move relatively faster than the other. This cause a separation among them and induce an internal Electrical field pulling them back. Let's call this - Ambipolar Field.

Here's is another key concept. The external field is pushing these two particles and the internal (ambipolar) field is keeping them together. The net effect is they are moving together with shared effective mobility (or diffusion coefficient).

I would recall the analogy Neamen introduced in his book way earlier. Of two drafting racing cars on Pg[59]. I realize this analogy fits here better. If two cars are racing on a circuit and one comes closely behind the other. The car ahead will decrease the air pressure for the one at the back. The behind car would be sped up and ahead car would be slowed down. Thus, they will be moving together.

Seemingly, this ambipolar field is locally stronger than the applied field such that the external field could not splice the ambipolar grouped particles. Why? I guess the separation among them is that small.
Next concern, why are there internal electric fields and still the body is charge neutral? It is not, I mean locally it is not. Or instantaneously It could not be. The domain within is very dynamically evolving. But the semiconductor on aggregate is charge neutral. This must be quasi-neutrality. (Quasi here feels like a misnomer).